# Detect Page Refresh in BHO

Tags: internet-explorer, bho

IE doesn't fire DocumentComplete & NavigateComplete2 events after a page refresh (F5).

This is apparently "by design", but it makes it hard to respond to a page reload.

What approaches out there have had the best success? What are the caveats? Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct method and it is hard to implement across different versions of IE. Although you can use combination of some events to achieve that. Be warned the following approaches are not fool proof.

**Links:**

1. [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/ieextensiondevelopment/thread/7a3a8d96-52f5-4ec0-a395-222c3dffa4b2/)
2. [Detecting the IE Refresh button](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3632/Detecting-the-IE-Refresh-button-using-IWebBrowser2)
3. [Refresh and DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE](http://petewarden.typepad.com/searchbrowser/2007/07/refresh-and-dis.html)

Comment: I can be possible ..i can detect page refresh in my BHO c#