# Trigger-corp cross-browser extensions framework: IE refresh issue

Tags: internet-explorer, trigger.io, bho, browser-extension

I'm using OpenForge framework for creating cross-browser extensions, and I'm currently issue with their IE extension build.

Trigger-corp browser extension: https://github.com/trigger-corp/browser-extensions/

My extension injects JavaScript in every browser page and everything works as expected except when I press F5 or refresh button to refresh page, after that code is not injected, and also code of framework. The only way to get code running again is to change url and press enter. Issue can be reproduced in any IE version.

I know that problem is similar to this one: [Detect Page Refresh in BHO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555627/detect-page-refresh-in-bho)

Anybody now what to change in code of this framework to fix this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Until IE starts firing DocumentComplete & NavigateComplete2 events after a page refresh we're pretty much out of luck as far as maintainable solutions goes.

Comment: Is there any workaround for this? It is not nice user experience when extension appears in page and disappear when user make refresh on page.